# Finding Best Unbiased Estimator of Uniform Distribution

Tags: statistical-inference, estimation, parameter-estimation

Let $X_i$, $i=1,...,n$ be iid with $f(x,\theta) = \frac{1}{2\theta}$ for $-\theta<x<\theta$. Find the best unbiased estimator of $\theta$ if one exists.

So I first tried $T(X)=X_{(n)}$, which gave me $$\mathbb{E}[T]=\frac{n-1}{n+1}\theta.$$ I thus concluded that $T(X)=\frac{n+1}{n-1}X_{(n)}$ should be an unbiased estimator.
Next, I wanted to check whether it is the best unbiased estimator using the Cramer Rao Lower Bound. It states 
$$\operatorname{Var}(T)\geq \frac{1}{I_X(\theta)},$$ 
so I first calculated the Fisher information for a single random variable. The calculation yields 
$$I_X(\theta)=\mathbb{E}_\theta[V(\theta,x)^2] = \int_{-\theta}^\theta\left(\partial_\theta\log\frac{1}{2\theta}\right)^{\!2}\frac{1}{2\theta}\,dx = \frac{1}{\theta^2}.$$ 
Thus the lower bound is $\dfrac{\theta^2}{n}$. Next, I computed the variance of the estimator 
$$\operatorname{Var}[T] = \int_{-\theta}^\theta \left(\frac{n+1}{n-1}\right)^{\!2}x^2n\frac{(x+\theta)^{n-1}}{2^n\theta^n}\,dx-\theta^2 = ... = \theta^2\frac{4n}{(n-1)^2(n-2)},$$ 
which is obviously lower than the lower bound. However, I am really unsure where I made a mistake. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: First of all, the information inequality does not apply to pdfs where support depends on parameter. And if by best unbiased estimator you mean in the sense of having minimum variance, then your proposed unbiased estimator is not the UMVUE.

Comment: I am not mistaken, the UMVUE of $\theta$ is $\frac{n+1}{n}\max_{1\le i\le n} |X_i|$, where $\max |X_i|$ is a complete sufficient statistic.

Comment: Thank you, but how would one go about proving that it is the UMVUE without this theorem?

Comment: What theorem have you used here? UMVUE in this case is shown by using the [Lehmann-Scheffe theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmann%E2%80%93Scheff%C3%A9_theorem).